# Using FPL (18/4 ) cable for 120v Smoke detectors

Tags: electrical, smoke-detectors

Currently have 18 smoke detectors inter-connected to a Vista 20 panel with 18/4 FPL cable.  We are selling (sold) the house, but have to replace all detectors since they are more than 10 years (Massachusetts Law). Current detectors are 4 wire, and unit replacement cost is ~$35.  The 120v units from Homedepot are ~$12.

My question is whether the existing FPL cable can be re-wired to the cheaper units, since the cable is rated to 300 volts.

Thanks in advance for assistance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm in no way an expert but I'm guessing code requires better than that when running 120VAC.

Comment: Even if you could find some way to adapt them, it's probably not going to be worth the time and effort to re-wire each of the 18 different smoke detectors. The cost between the cheap ones and the ones that you know will work with your panel and wiring is only $23 each, or around $400 for all o fthem - that doesn't seem like a lot of money to put into the sale of a home  that's large enough to need 18 different smoke detectors.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely cannot use that cable for line voltage smoke detectors, for several reasons. One big one is that you cannot have a typical circuit smaller than 15A, which would require #14cu minimum. OK, I have to say, it is technically possible, but entirely impractical.

IMO replacing "alarm system" heads with line voltage smoke detectors is a downgrade and rather hackish.

Just how big is this house that you have 18(!!) smokes??

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Maybe

Here is why: The cable may be rated for 300 volts but it is not #14 gauge minimum size for power and lighting as stated here:

> **(A) Minimum Size of Conductors.** The minimum size of conductors shall be as shown in Table 310.106(A), except as permitted elsewhere in this Code

Table 310.106(A) shows the minimum size to be #14 gauge wire.

However, if you get a 7 amp breaker or fuse marked for use with #18 ga wire or a special class of fuse, you could use this section

> **Article 240.4(D)(1)** 18 AWG Copper. 7 amperes, provided all the following conditions are met:
>
> (1) Continuous loads do not exceed 5.6 amperes. (2) Overcurrent protection is provided by one of the following: a. Branch-circuit-rated circuit breakers listed and marked for use with 18 AWG copper wire b. Branch-circuit-rated fuses listed and marked for use with 18 AWG copper wire c. Class CC, Class J, or Class T fuses

This would be very strange in a house though so your inspector may not want to allow it.

Good luck!

Comment: This is all well and good. Now find a 7A circuit breaker for use with 18ga wire, to fit ANY standard residential breaker panel. ...... I'll wait.

Comment: It doesn't have to fit the breaker panel. It could be installed in its own enclosure. And as I said it would be a strange thing for a house.

Comment: Regardless of how technically possible something is, sometimes the correct answer is it can't be done.

Comment: No the correct answer is that it can be done it just may not be to your liking.

Comment: And I disagree. It's got nothing to do with my liking. I can make anything work. It's got to do with our target audience.

Comment: Well the code says what it says. I may not agree with it either but there it is.

Comment: The inspector may not agree with it either.  My issue is the installer wasn't thinking about putting mains power on this cable, and specced and installed it in a manner fitting low voltage cable.  There's more to NM than 300v insulation, so that cable may not be rated for power use as installed.   Somewhere here, there's sure to be a deviation from code (unless the installer was Rain Man) so you could buy all those smoke detectors only to find you can't use them.

Comment: And as a buyer, I *hate* when the seller buys new fixtures just to sell the place.  It's usually cheap tenant-grade junk, or the apocryhal white carpet... Which I then have to suffer with or pay again to replace.  I wish the seller would just agree with me not to replace it, stipulate that it needs doing, knock the price down by what he would've spent on the junk, and leave it to me so I can pick what I want.

Comment: @WolfHarper - I upticked your comment because I totally agree with you. Problem is that selling comes before buying. The sellers agent, thinking to justify their sellers fee for the lowest amount of work, are the typical folks that tell the sellers what they think is needed to make the house "present and show well". Of course there are the "professional" house flippers, who also often property agents themselves, are also some of the ones getting in the way of a transaction such as you visualize.

Comment: @WolfHarper - the problem, of course, is that buyers are generally wiling to pay *more* than the value of the cheap fixtures (even when they *know* they are cheap) -Throwing a few thousands dollars of cheap fixtures and other touchup into a house can recoup many times that in a higher sales price since a house that looks better sells higher. Though in this case, the replacement may not be negotiable since the asker mentions Massachusetts law in driving the decision to replace the 10+ year fire alarms.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.  I will stick with the LV smokes, and spend the extra money.  I had already given the buyers $7500 credit toward closing for repairs (none of which ended up being needed).  Since the smokes are code related, they say this does not apply.